# Openvino: Problem when trying to load CPU plugin in Qt

Tags: c++, qt5, intel, openvino

After installing and successfully run the OpenVino demos in my PC I start implementing a basic application in Qt with this library. I made the linking as Intel's [documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/OpenVINO-InferEngine) describes and the application successfully compiled.

```
auto plugin = PluginDispatcher({L""}).getPluginByDevice("CPU");

auto netBuilder = new CNNNetReader();
netBuilder->ReadNetwork("../TestModel/squeezenet1.1.xml");
netBuilder->ReadWeights("../TestModel/squeezenet1.1.bin");

auto network = netBuilder->getNetwork();
netBuilder->getNetwork().setBatchSize(1);
```

The application pops an exception when debugger reach getPluginByDevice call (getSuitablePlugin method from ie_plugin_dispacher.hpp (line 73)).

[image]

I am using MSVC2017 64bit with Qt 5.11.1 in a Windows 10 machine. The .pro file library call is:

```
#OpenVino
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/inference_engine/include
LIBS += -L$$PWD/inference_engine/lib/intel64/Release
LIBS += -linference_engine -llibiomp5md
```

Is anyone experienced the same or has an idea what's going on?

Thanks in advance,

Thanasis

Comment: In Release mode the Application runs normally though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The release libraries were causing the problem. When I switched to the debug ones (inference_engined.lib insted of inference_engine.lib) the application run successfully.

**EDIT**

I paste the code from .pro file in case someone face the same problem.

```
#OpenVino
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/inference_engine/include

CONFIG(release, debug|release):BuildVar=release
CONFIG(debug, debug|release):BuildVar=debug

equals(BuildVar,debug) {
    message(Debug Mode)
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/inference_engine/lib/intel64/Debug
    LIBS += -linference_engined
}

equals(BuildVar,release) {
    message(Release Mode)
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/inference_engine/lib/intel64/Release
    LIBS += -linference_engine
}
```